# C# Process Name, but not like 'chrome(.exe)' but like 'Chrome'

Tags: c#, process

Maybe a weird question, but i did not really know how to ask it, hope i made my point clear in the title.

Code i have so far:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the process that is currently running on the foreground
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Proces object containing all information about the process that is running on the foreground</returns>
    public static Process GetCurrentRunningProcess()
    {
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
        IntPtr activeWindow = GetForegroundWindow();

        foreach (Process process in processes)
        {
            if (process.MainWindowHandle == activeWindow)
                return process;
        }

        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the Foreground Window using the user32.dll
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The handle of the window</returns>
    [DllImport("user32", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
```

This is what I'm doing right now, and it get's me the Process which contains a ProcessName. In my case I get 'chrome' where i actually want 'Chrome' or when I have notepad(.exe) i want Notepad. Is there a way to achieve this? Or do I have to make a list with program names and compare it with the ProcessName?

Comment: Why notepad.exe should return Noteped, and chrome.exe - Chrome?

Comment: It seems an unsafe assumption that the foreground window is the MainWindowHandle of a process. How are you planning to use the text that you've obtained? Maybe there's a better way to do what you're planning.

Comment: This is obviously not possible. The process doesn't know the name the application was marketed under. Sometimes the name of the executable is similar (as in the case of Notepad and Chrome), but other times it's completely different. `WinWord.exe` corresponds to Microsoft Office Word, for example—how is the computer to know that? And all bets are certainly off with more obscure applications.

Comment: @Cody: Notepad is sometimes Блокнот, in case of Russian Windows. So it doesn't work even for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the most part, a lookup table is better than trying to reformat the executable name as many programs are not named in the mosst obvious way (Microsoft Word is WINWORD.exe).

I haven't tested `Process.MainWindowTitle`, but you may find that it includes the names of open documents and other rubbish you don't want. Best to test it before trying anything fancy.

Comment: I tried that, but when browsing (with Chrome atleast) you would have 'C# Process Name but not like 'chrome(.exe)' but like 'Chrome' as the MainWindowTitle

Answer (score 0):

What about replacing the "(.exe)" and casting the first letter to upper? Or do I miss the point?

```
public string ToUpperFirstLetter(string source)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
        return String.Empty;
    // convert to char array of the string
    var letters = source.Replace(".exe", String.Empty).ToCharArray();
    // upper case the first char
    letters[0] = Char.ToUpper(letters[0], CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    // return the array made of the new char array
    return new string(letters);
}
```

Comment: Nope, Teamspeak 3's exe file is called ts3_client.exe, with this method resulting in 'Ts3_client' where i wanted 'Teamspeak 3 Client'

Answer (score 0):

What you can just use is `Process.MainWindowTitle`

Comment: I tried that, but when browsing (with Chrome atleast) you would have 'C# Process Name but not like 'chrome(.exe)' but like 'Chrome' as the MainWindowTitle